# Check with sd_bus if reloading a process is successfull

Tags: nginx, ipc, reload, dbus

i'm trying to check with sd_bus_get_property() if reloading for example nginx or php was successfull.

For that the properties "ActiveState" and "SubState" are interesting.

But if i for example intentionally make a mistake in the nginx.conf and try to reload nginx, i get the following states:

> ...
> ACTIVE_STATE: reloading
> SUB_STATE: reload
> ACTIVE_STATE: reloading
> SUB_STATE: reload
> ACTIVE_STATE: reloading
> SUB_STATE: reload
> ACTIVE_STATE: active
> SUB_STATE: running

So if nginx is active and running, after the failed reload the states just get back to "active" and "running".

Is there a way to safely check, if the reload fails?

Thanks!

Comment: You can run and check the `nginx -t` return code to ensure the new configuration is correct before reloading nginx.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I know the configuration check via terminal or system-call, but i search for a solution with sd_bus for different processes. Nginx here was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up managing the processes differently:

As an example for Nginx and PHP-FPM:

**Nginx:**

1. Get PID's from all Nginx-Worker Processes (systemd1.Manager => GetUnitProcesses).
2. Reload Nginx.
3. Check all 50ms if there is a new PID in the List of
   Worker-Processes.
4. If after 200-300ms there is still no new PID, so reload most likely
   failed.

---

**PHP-FPM:**

On PHP-FPM it seems easier, as PHP-FPM sets the "ActiveState" to "failed" if reloading fails.
I thought i just could wait for a change of the "ActiveState" after the State is "reloading", but if reloading fails, php-fpm sets the State first back to "active" an then quickly to "failed".
Therefore i wait also for PHP-FPM 200-300ms and then check the State.

If someone has a better idea, please tell me... Thanks!